# Merging two Geopandas dataframe based on their coordinates

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, coordinates, geopandas

I want to join two geopandas data frames based on their coordinate. I tried:

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1, on= 'geometry')
df3 = gpd.merge(df1, df2, on= 'geometry')
```

But I always get the same error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Point'
```

Comment: Take a look at the geopandas docs. Geopandas merge is like pandas merge - it’s based on the index. You’re looking for geopandas.sjoin.

Comment: addition: spatial joins on two points only work if the coordinates are identical - which in real-life data is not always the case. if you notice missing rows after the spatial join, you could apply a reasonably small buffer (geopandas.GeoSeries.buffer) to one of the point geometries before the join

Answer (score -1):

I changed the geopandas back to pandas dataframe and then merged on the geometry column.